# Regex lookbeaind only when contains colon

Tags: c#, regex

Today I use c# **Regex.IsMatch** function to matching **key:value** format.

I have some code that checking if string format is: **key:value** (like: H:15).

The Regex pattern that I am using today is: **[D,H,M,S]:[1-9]+\d?**

I what to add the option for default key, when the input is **15**, I would like to consider it like: **H:15**

So, I need to improve my Regex to support **key:value** or **only value** (without colon), **H:15** is good and **15** is also good

I tried to use the **or** regex condition (|) something like : **([D,H,M,S]:[1-9]+\d?)|([1-9]+\d?)**

But now it match more thinks like **:1** and **H:01** that are bad input for me.

I try to use also lookbehind regex without success

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Nadav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
\b(?:[DHMS]:|(?<!:))[1-9][0-9]*\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iP7cA0/4)

So, either match `[DHMS]:` or a word boundary not preceded by `:`.

Also, `[1-9]+\d?` looks very suspicious to me, so I replaced it with `[1-9][0-9]*`. Note that in .NET `\d` is *not* equivalent to `[0-9]` because it includes Unicode digits as well.

Comment: I don't believe this is true: "Note that in .NET \d is not equivalent to [0-9]".

Comment: Also, your expression is lacking word boundaries on the front, so you'll get a false positive for the input: 4324H:123. It might be better as "\b(?:[DHMS]:|(?<!:))[1-9][0-9]*\b". Nadav, my answer below also provides a candidate to try.

Comment: @Colin You're right about `\b`, I moved it to the front, thanks! But I'm right about `\d`, you can try this to confirm: `Regex.IsMatch("೬", @"\d")`

Comment: @Lucas. Very interesting regarding the Kannada digit! It doesn't totally surprise me that other cultures don't use 0-9 as a number system, but I'd sort of assumed the universality up to now. Good tip!

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski you can please update the demo as the update the regex ? Thanks

Comment: @Nadav oops, actually I've already updated the demo, but I forgot to update the link in the answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you wants something like this,

```
@"^(?:[DHMS]:)?[1-9]\d*$"
```

`[DHMS]` matches a single character from the given list. `?` after the non-capturing group will turn the key part to an optional one. `\d*` matches zero or more digit characters.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response

This regex is match also **:1** , **H:01** that are bad regex for me because **01** is not a number and colon don't need to be in the input if there is no key before them.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Avinash just beat me to it, but I added word boundaries with this expression, which works well in tests.

```
\b(?<=[DHMS]:)?[1-9]\d*\b
```